# Multiple Inheritance in ActionScript 3.0 (in beginner talk)

Tags: actionscript-3, multiple-inheritance, movieclip, simplebutton

I think it's called Multiple Inheritance.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm pretty much a beginner with AS3 and am having some trouble with it.  Basically, if I were to do this:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    public class ClassName extends MovieClip {
        var movieClipObjectExample:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        var simpleButtonObjectExample:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton();
        public function ClassName {
            //constructor code
        }
    }
}
```

then I would get an error because I didn't subclass SimpleButton.  If I were to replace

```
extends MovieClip
```

with

```
extends SimpleButton
```

then I would get an error because I didn't subclass MovieClip.  I understand that AS3 can't do multiple inheritance directly, but instead, there's some kind of workaround using Interfaces.  Could someone explain to me in the best beginner terms you can come up with on how to do this?  Or what the simplest workaround is, if Interfaces aren't?

I think the difference I found in my question versus other people's is that I need multiple inheritance from Flash's default classes, rather than custom ones, so it's necessary to have multiple inheritance here.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems like you are pretty confused (and what you wrote is incorrect). Why do you need to subclass both Movieclip and Simplebutton?

Comment: You don't need to subclass ANY of them. You think that if you are using Movieclip, Simplebutton, Netstream, StageWebView, Socket, etc. in one class you would have to subclass them all? Of course not. You just need them import statements (e.g. *import flash.display.Movieclip*) Leave your class extending movieclip and import the classes you will use. EDIT: Also, please do not remove your comments cos it looks like I am talking with myself.

Comment: So you mean use import statements in the class rather than in the package?

Comment: It worked, thank you so much Fygo!  That was bugging me.

Comment: If you import something it means you are able to use that definition. I am not quite sure what you mean by *use import statements in the class rather than in the package*. You need to import all the classes that you are going to use if they are not in the same package as the class you want to use them in. Most IDE's do it automatically for you. If you import all the package (with the asterisk), it works the same. I assume that's what you meant, didn't you?

Comment: In the code above, in the package before the class, I have an import flash.display.*; statement.  I didn't have that statement in the class.  I added that statement in the class, below the public class line, and it fixed the issue.  That's the only change I made.  So the import statement is now in two locations, but it works.  I'm not too sure of the wording there, but that's what I meant.  And in 8 hours, when I can answer my own question, I'll post the updated code fix.

Comment: How 2 locations, where is the 2nd? I see only one (also, never NEVER post your corrected code in the question, overwriting the previous one!)

Comment: @BigTarantula99 There is no reason that should have fixed it; something is wrong.  Even though I think the language might technically allow you to put import statements inside of class definitions, this is not where you're supposed to put them (unless using MXML).  You're supposed to only write the same import statement one time, and you're only supposed to put it outside the class's definition (unless using MXML, which you're not using in this example)...

Comment: ...That being said, the import statement you have up there should have worked.  If re-writing it inside your class made things suddenly work, then there's definitely more to the story.  Maybe we're not seeing all the code?  Or perhaps there's another issue.  But if you had it in the package definition, just above the class, it should have worked without being copied inside of the class.  Also, interfaces are not multiple inheritance.  They're kind of like 1-and-one-quarter inheritance.

Comment: @Fygo Of course not, I'm gonna put it in the answer.  I added the same `import flash.display.*;` statement (seen below `package {`) to below the `public class` statement.  That's all I had to do, and it works.

Comment: @Panzercrisis Interesting.  I don't understand it either.  That is literally all the code I have.  Anyway, if you want to take this into further account and try to find what's wrong, be my guest.  But I'm not building a gigantic app, just a very small one.  So for me, as long as I fixed the errors, I'm fine.  Thanks anyway.  Also, I don't need to continue my question about the interfaces as I've fixed my problem.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I guess the import statement was not there but the OP added it, the question was edited 2 hrs ago after I posted about import. Well, maybe I am wrong, I have really big difficulties following it so I am off. :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been fixed!  I needed to add one more line of code:

```
import flash.display.*;
```

underneath the `public class` statement.  So basically, I needed the `import` statement twice, one in the package, and one in the class.

Thank you everyone!